# Invalid Escape sequence java

Tags: java

I am trying do that but it keeps give me error invalid escape format. I was trying to remove some backslash but didn't work

```
private string chars = "(lP+" (\\w+)/\\d{3} \\d+ \\w+ \\S+\\s?\"?($|-|[\\w\\\\\.@]+)\"?")";
```

Comment: You are closing the String at index 5. If you want to have the '"' character in your string, you need to escape it.

Comment: Your string is `"(lp+"` and there it ends. The rest - `(\\w+...` does not belong to the string anymore

Comment: Sorry,I didn't get you exactly

Answer (score 6):

- String should have a capital 'S'
- You've missed esacaping a couple of the quotation marks.
- You have a run of five backslashes, which should either be 4 or 6.

You *probably* want something like this instead...

```
private String chars = "(lP+\" (\\w+)/\\d{3} \\d+ \\w+ \\S+\\s?\"?($|-|[\\w\\\\\\.@]+)\"?\")";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private String chars = "(lP+\" (\\w+)/\\d{3} \\d+ \\w+ \\S+\\s?\"?(\\$|-|[\\w\\\\.@]+)\"?\")";
```

Comment: String needs to be capitalized.

Comment: I just copy pasted his code =) But thnx for pointing it out!